# When and why did Q's son learn to create spatial flexures?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-q

In Q2, Tom Paris asks Q's son if he'd like to take the helm in the Flyer. Q states that Qs typically wouldn't use humanoid technology, but since he had lost his powers the situation was decidedly different. So he takes the helm.

Later, Q and Icheb are together in the Flyer when the former states that he once learned how to open spatial flexures. Presumably this was accomplished with the use of technology (otherwise how would the human Q know how to do it with the Flyer's tech).

I don't have a problem with Q just "knowing" how to open a flexure after losing his powers, retaining this knowledge. But why and when would he have "learned" this? As a Q, why he be trained with technology?

One possibility is that Q trains his son in this method (for whatever reason) after the latter loses his powers. Or perhaps prior to, since Q possibly would know the future and of his son's ban. Which would mean that Q Sr. was ultimately responsible for the whole incident involving the Chokuzan and the resultant test.

Comment: We see the Female Q subverting Federation technology in [The Q and the Grey](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/306.htm) to open a rift into the Q Continuum. Clearly the ability to use tech to achieve what the Q *normally* do by snapping their fingers simply comes with being an advanced species.

Comment: Agreed. I'll have to listen to the quote again. The son made it sound like he was trained with technology, which is absurd.